# C++ Having trouble with sscanf pattern

Tags: c++, scanf

I am trying to "extract" the name and the next integer. When I run this, I get a run-time error. I have tested without the string and it runs fine.

```
// Test string
std::string show = "BlahBlah 3";

// Pickup string and int
std::string nameString;
int id;
sscanf(show.c_str(), "%s %i", &nameString, &id);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sscanf()` is a C function, not a C++ function.  It has no concept of `std::string`.  You cannot use `sscanf()` to read into a `std::string` variable like you have attempted.  You need to pre-allocate a `char` buffer for `sscanf()` to read into, and then assign that to your `std::string`, eg:

```
// Test string
std::string show = "BlahBlah 3";

// Pickup string and int
std::string nameString;
char buffer[32];
int id;
if (sscanf(show.c_str(), "%.31s %i", buffer, &id) == 2)
{
    nameString = buffer;
    // use values as needed...
}
else
{
    // values not parsed...
}
```

Or, you can preallocate a `std::string` and have `sscanf()` fill it:

```
// Test string
std::string show = "BlahBlah 3";

// Pickup string and int
std::string nameString;
int id;
nameString.resize(32);
if (sscanf(show.c_str(), "%.31s %i", &nameString[0], &id) == 2)
{
    nameString.resize(std::strlen(nameString.c_str()));
    // use values as needed...
}
else
{
    // values not parsed...
}
```

Since you are using C++, a better option is to use C++ classes to parse the string, eg:

```
// Test string
std::string show = "BlahBlah 3";

// Pickup string and int
std::string nameString;
int id;

std::istringstream iss(show);
if (iss >> nameString >> id)
{
    // use values as needed...
}
else
{
    // values not parsed...
}
```

Comment: @Galik at the time, I really meant `reserve()`. I was preallocating the string's capacity, not its size, then letting `sscanf()` fill the memory, then finally setting the size to the number of characters read. But I guess the resize will wipe the read characters, so it does  make more sense to use `resize()` instead of `reserve()` for the preallocation.

Answer (score 6):

Well, what you're doing wrong is using `sscanf()`, a C library function, with `std::string`, a C++ class. `sscanf()` does not know anything about C++ classes. `sscanf()` existed long before C++ was just a glimmer in Stroustrup's eye...